# problem with zsh interactive shell

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh, urxvt

When I use zsh in interactive mode, I get some glitches. This mainly happens when the command spills over onto a new line and I use backspace, with backspace leaving behind some glitches on the screen and moving the cursor to an odd position.

It happens in a VT, in xterm and urxvt, although it is most noticeable with my chosen terminal, urxvt.

When I use zsh as a login shell, it does not happen at all.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Your description is a bit vague. Are you using a fancy prompt? (Does it still happen with a simple prompt?) Is the prompt the same in  non-login and login instances of *zsh*? Are you using any non-ASCII characters in your prompt or in your input (e.g. a UTF-8 terminal with multibyte UTF-8 text involved)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help if you showed what your `PROMPT` variable is set to when it's not working, but it's likely that you have escape sequences that are being counted in the width of the prompt. You can fix this by editing the value so that those sequences are surrounded by `%{ ... %}`.

Comment: That was it exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

The shell and your terminal program have to agree on:

- the size, capabilities and behaviour of the window;
- the number of characters displayed on it; these numbers could start to differ e.g. when one side assumes Unicode while the other assumes Latin encoding, or when a backspace isn't handled correctly.

Your termcap / terminfo settings, and the configuration of your terminal program, must be consistent, or you get exactly the behaviour you describe.

Sadly, I'm not as proficient with these settings as I would like to be, and can't really pinpoint what you should change where. (Have to leave room for others to earn upvotes, huh? ;-) )